# LINQ Query To Return Duplicates Exclusively

Tags: linq, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm working on this LINQ query. I'd like the resulting list return a list of records that contain duplicates exclusively, based on the EMailAddress1 field and grouped by the EMailAddress1 field.

For instance:

1. emailaddress1@gmail.com
2. emailaddress1@gmail.com
3. emailaddress2@gmail.com
4. emailaddress2@gmail.com
5. emailaddress2@gmail.com
6. emailaddress3@gmail.com
7. emailaddress3@gmail.com

etc.

Any advice on this? Thanks.

```
 var contacts = (from c in xrm.ContactSet 
                        where c.StateCode != 1 
                        orderby c.EMailAddress1, c.CreatedOn 
                        descending select new { 
                            c.FirstName, 
                            c.LastName, 
                            c.EMailAddress1, 
                            c.ContactId, 
                            c.CreatedOn }).ToList();
```

Comment: It is neccesary to be a Query? Why not use the native one "find duplicates"

Comment: @Sxntk Well I'm doing other things with this list....I suppose I could iterate over each element in the list and compare each other, like this:foreach (var c in contacts) { 
            
            foreach (var b in contacts)

                if (b == c) {

                    //Do something
                }
            
            }  But what about the grouping? Is there way I can group each "EMailAddress1" field in the list?

Comment: You can't group with LinQ CRM, you can query all the records on account and with that list use the normal LinQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your previous query:

```
var duplicatedEmails = (from c in contacts
                        group c by c.EMailAddress1 into g
                        where g.Count() > 1
                        select g.Key).ToList();
var duplicatedContacts = contacts.Where(c => duplicatedEmails.Contains(c.EMailAddress1));
```